# Apply multiple conditions to a capturing group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need to extract from a text all the words which match these two requirements:

1. Contain at least one uppercase letter
2. Don't fully consist of uppercase characters.

So, **Word** and **WorD** are correct captures, but **word** and **WORD** aren't.

So, I can capture all the words using a `\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b` Regex, but I don't know how to add the uppercase letters condition here.

As about the requirement #1, I [tried](https://regex101.com/r/aEDluS/1) to use a positive lookahead here like this:

`\b(?=.*[A-Z]+)([a-zA-Z]+)\b` , but now it captures all the words from a line if this line has at least one uppercase letter.

Is it even possible to apply additional conditions to a capturing group?
I can process this in my application's code but I'd really prefer to fit all those requirements in a single Regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(?=[A-Z]*[a-z])(?=[a-z]*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z]+)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aEDluS/2)

Actually, you do not even need the capturing group, `([a-zA-Z]+)` can be usually replaced with `[a-zA-Z]+`, but it depends where you are using the regex.

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?=[A-Z]*[a-z])` - a positive lookahead that requires a lowercase letter after 0+ uppercase ones
- `(?=[a-z]*[A-Z])` - a positive lookahead that requires a uppercase letter after 0+ lowercase ones
- `([a-zA-Z]+)` - Group 1: 1 or more letters
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: Works perfect, thank you!
So, the only solution to such a problem would be just copy the core pattern from the capture group to each additional lookaround and there is no way to specify additional conditions only to the text that was matched to this group, right?

Comment: No, that is not possible.